# Get a iqueryable items which do not exists on another list using lambda expression

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, lambda, iqueryable

I have an IQueryable(Of T) and a list of depended items List(of T). I am trying to achieve an IQueryable(Of T) which will exclude all the items in the List(of T).

```
 Dim returnQuery As IQueryable(Of POCO.ClassName) = GetTheQuery(...)
 Dim excludeLists As List(Of POCO.ClassName) = GetExcludedList(...)

 returnQuery = returnQuery.Except(excludeLists)
```

The error occurs when trying the execute the result for IQueryable.

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'POCO.ClassName'. Only
>   primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

It seems except will not work in this case. So how can I exclude the list items using lambda expressions.

Comment: This is interesting.  I think you would be better off not using a lambda and just using Linq.  Is there a specific reason why you need to implement lambda?

Comment: @Airborne no specific reasons. I know the way it can be done by Linq but wondering is there any way to achieve by Lambda or not..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the typical example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb300779(v=vs.100).aspx uses doubles, and combined with the error you got, it is clear `Except` only works on primitives like doubles.

So you'll have to use Linq, and there is nothing wrong with that.

```
returnQuery = returnQuery.Where(item => !excludeLists.Contains(item))
```